# Send "hit enter" with Bash Script

Tags: bash, serial-port, modem

I'm running some bash script to send AT commands to my modem. For the commands to run, it's necessary to hit "enter" (return) for the modem to "read" it.
I have a looping, with a part like this:

```
echo AT+SBDWT=$number >/dev/ttyUSB0
xvkbd -text "\r"
echo AT+SBDIX >/dev/ttyUSB0
xvkbd -text "\r"
sleep 15
done
```

xvkbd was one solution I've came across, but it seems to be working just for the first time. With this script, I need to hit enter as many times as I send commands, but it's not working properly.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I couldn't add a comment to ask you this question, but I want to see if i can help, so I am posting an answer.

Instead of using xvkbd, doesn't

```
echo -ne '\r' > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

or

```
echo -ne '\n' > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

work?

Comment: That was the first shot, and it seemed to work fine with only one AT command. I think I may have to use some sleep time inbetween the commands, since they may take a little time to actually run, and that's the reason this wasn't working. I'm trying this now, thanks for your reply!

Comment: It is possible.  If this is a real modem, the response may be a little slow.  Or maybe you can also try "\n\r"

Comment: hey, kiwo. The main problem was actually the delay for the modem to answer the command. Your solution ('\r') is perfect when I run it with some sleep time in between the commands. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I can help. :)